# Is it possible to solve this set of equations regarding ECG Limb leads?

Tags: linear-algebra

ECG Limb leads are bipolar leads which measure electrical potential. I'm working with some ECG signal data and am trying to extract unipolar potentials from the bipolar ones read in.

Given the following equations, with only  I, II, III, aVF, aVR and aVL can you solve for LA and RA? or LA + RA ?

Given: I, II, III, aVF, aVR and aVL

Unknown: LA, RA, LL

Equations:

I = LA - RA

II = LL - RA

III = LL - LA

aVF = LL - (RA + LA)/2

aVR = RA – (LA + LL)/2

aVL = LA – (RA + LL)/2

I've been trying to figure this out, but I figured you can get II by using

II = I + III

so they are linearly dependent, but I can't get into the equations to figure out RA and LA, it just has me running in circles.

Comment: Please state clearly which quantities are known, and which are unknown. Also, have you tried to do a numerical example to get an idea how the land lies? Such additions also serve to dispel the inevitable thought that you are trying to outsource your homework. The point is **not** whether this is homework, but whether it **looks like** HW. A reader who has never heard of ECG Limb leads will be unable to judge that. You see that the question has already started attracting negative attention. Clarifying such points and adding your own thoughts will help.

Comment: Edited, thanks for the tips, first time poster here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it is impossible to work out the values of $LA$ and $RA$ from these equations.

The reason is the following. You can add a constant, any constant $C$ to the values of $LA, RA$ and $LL$. But this addition process will not show in the equations at all. In other words, the new values, $LA+C, RA+C$ and $LL+C$ satisfy the same equations. For example
$$(LA+C)-(RA+C)=LA+C-RA-C=LA-RA=I$$
and
$$
\begin{aligned}
(LA+C)-\frac12[(RA+C)+(LL+C)]&=LA-\frac12[RA+LL]+\left(C-\frac12[C+C]\right)\\
&=LA-\frac12[RA+LL]\\
&=aVL.
\end{aligned}
$$
This shows that the new values satisfy the same equations as the old values (without the additive constant $C$). Therefore we cannot find a unique value to those variables.

The same applies to the sum $LA+RA$. Adding the constant $C$ to the three unknowns will add $2C$ to this sum.

---

I hazard a guess that from the technical meaning of these variables you can see (but I cannot for I don't know what they mean) that this additive constant ambiguity must be there. In a sense the equations simply tell us that the variables $I,II,III$, $aVL, aVR, aVF$ are (weighted) differences of the three unknowns. But the origin of the axes those unknowns reside on is left in the dark here.

Comment: Ok. I googled up [ECG Limb Leads](https://lifeinthefastlane.com/ecg-library/limb-lead-reversals/). My understanding is that the variables are voltages. Voltages in general don't have definite values, only voltage differences do. For example, one of the electrodes may be grounded, and you could then assume that to have value zero. But which one is grounded (if any)? Don't ask me!